# modify entity outside transaction

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I just started with kotlin exposed and looking into documentation as i am really surprised with semantic of working with "detached entities".  To keep things straight:
Is it possible to modify entity object OUTSIDE of transaction and then
attach it (effectively to have it updated) in other transactions ?

I have worked for a number of years with hibernate/JPA and it has been some kind of "standard" flow in which:

- entity object is returned from DAO(repository) layer to a "service layer",
- it is then modified in a service layer,
- finally it is sent back to DAO layer for changes to be persisted.

In kotlin exposed if i try to modify a single scalar property outside of transaction  sth like

```
 location.postcode = "other postCode"
```

an exception (No transaction in context.) is thrown.

Is it intended ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll work. [Official document](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/Transactions) says all CRUD operations should be done in transaction.